# NSString potential leak

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks

When I build and analyze my project on XCode, I obtain a 'warning' on the following line:

```
NSString *contactEmail = (NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emailInfo, 0);
```

The message is: Potential leak on object allocated on line ... and stored into contactEmail.

Is there any error on that line?

**UPDATE**

I get the same 'warning' with this line of code:

```
ABMultiValueRef emailInfo = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);
```

But here, I can't do this:

```
[emailInfo release];
```

I'm developing for iPhone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex` is a "Copy" function, which follows [the "Create Rule"](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-103029). You need to call `CFRelease` to release it after finish using it.

```
NSString *contactEmail = (NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emailInfo, 0);
...
if (contactEmail != nil)
  CFRelease((CFTypeRef) contactEmail);
```

Comment: Since the object is being used as an NSString, it's much more natural to send a release or autorelease message to it than to check for nil, cast it back again and call CFRelease()

Comment: The object *is* an `NSString`.

Comment: @Williham: (1) `ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex` returns CoreFoundation objects, which may be a CFString, or other stuff e.g. CFNumber. In fact OP should check before assuming the result is a string, but that's rare case. (2) A CFString can be toll-free-bridged to use NSString methods. A CFString is part of the class-cluster of NSString, but the class is actually NSCFString. @Jason: I prefer to use CF API for CF stuff, but yeah your suggestion also works.

Comment: I've updated my question. I also have the same problem with **ABMultiValueRef emailInfo = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);**

Comment: @KennyTM: (1) Obviously, "The object *is* an `NSString`, assuming it is a `CFString`.". Given a name like `emailInfo`, this seems somewhat likely. (2) An `NSCFString` is also an `NSString`; and saying that CFString *can* be toll-free-briged makes it seem optional. It *is* bridged.

Comment: @Vans: `CFRelease(emailInfo);`

Comment: @KennyTM: I prefer that too, but the OP is obviously preferring to use the Foundation classes, so it is more natural to treat the object as a Foundation class, that's all I was saying.

Answer (score 1):

1. The cast is somewhat pointless.
2. The line might leak, unless you release or autorelease it somewhere.

**Edit:** For brevity:

```
NSString *contactEmail = [(NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emailInfo, 0) autorelease];
```

(The cast might still be pointless, I'm unsure as to how the compiler would handle trying sending a message directly to a CFTypeRef.)

Comment: I've updated my question. I also have the same problem with **ABMultiValueRef emailInfo = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);**