# Memory leak when declaring NSString from ABRecordCopyValue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-leaks, abaddressbook

I am using the following line of code...

```
NSString *clientFirstName = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
```

The 'analyse' feature on Xcode is saying that this giving rise to a potential memory leak. I am not releasing clientFirstName at all as I have neither `alloc` or `retain`'d it.

However, I am conscious that ABRecordCopyValue may not be returning an object as say a command like `[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:someArray]` would which might mean I am indeed creating a new object that I control and must release.

Keen to hear thoughts...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any sort of copy returns an object with a `retainCount` of 1, so you need to `release` it via `CFRelease()`.

See the [doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Reference/AddressBook/C/ABRecordRef/Reference/reference.html):

> You are responsible for releasing this object.

Comment: Yep - that's worked. Still don't fully understand CFRelease yet!

Comment: `CFRelease()` does the same as sending a `release`-message to an object.

Comment: @Jenox: From just a quick observation, I don't think your answer is completely correct. I think it is incomplete. Nothing personal!

Comment: Would you mind telling me what exactly you think is incomplete?

Comment: @Jenox If I am not wrong, I think you should specify to check the object and if object is not `nil`, then it is better to execute functions on the object as there is no point executing `release` for a nil object. You should specify this especially as Ben Thompson looks to be a fairly new programmer in objective-C. Hope this is fine. :)

Comment: But being able to send messages to `nil` objects is such a great feature in Objective-C! I think he should - as a new programmer - know of this awesome stuff...

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this link. It has same as yours:

[NSString potential leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638129/nsstring-potential-leak)

Refer to answer of **KennyTM**:

> `ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex` is a "Copy" function, which follows
> [the "Create
> Rule"](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-103029).
> You need to call `CFRelease` to release it after finish using it.
>
> ```
> NSString *contactEmail = (NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emailInfo, 0);
> ...
> if (contactEmail != nil)
>   CFRelease((CFTypeRef) contactEmail);
> ```

Release your object `clientFirstName` using `CFRelease`.

Add the code below:

```
if(clientFirstName != nil)
{
     CFRelease((CFTypeRef) clientFirstName);
}
```

**NOTE:** Do not forget to check if `clientFirstName` is not nil. It is better to have a practice of checking that object is not `nil` before executing any function on it as it saves us from potential crashes though not in this case, but in many cases

### Edit

Also as @Dondragmer says in one of the comments below:

I think even this should solve the problem:

```
[clientFirstName release];
```

Comment: Since `NSString` is toll-free bridged with `CFStringRef`, it is sufficient to call `[contactEmail release]` instead of `CFRelease((CFTypeRef) contactEmail)`.  Both statements will have the same effect, but the first is safer: it doesn't matter if you call the Objective-C `release` on a `nil` object.

Comment: @Dondragmer: No Offense to you but I still prefer that it is better to have a practice of checking that object is not `nil` before executing any function on it as it saves us from potential crashes in some cases. Also I would prefer the second `CFRelease((CFTypeRef) contactEmail)`.

Comment: @Dondragmer: Also would like to ask you why you feel `[contactEmail release];` is safer? I believe second one is the one that should be used.

Comment: if the programmer makes a mistake and calls `[contactEmail release];` without checking for `nil`, it won't crash.  Calling `CFRelease((CFTypeRef) contactEmail);` in the same circumstances will cause a crash.  As long as memory isn't being corrupted, not crashing is safer than crashing.  It is also possible to call `[contactEmail autorelease];` immediate after creating the string, putting allocation and deallocation at the same point in the program.

Comment: @Dondragmer: Ok thanks for the information. I have edited my answer and added your point in EDIT section of answer. Thanks for the information :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand how ObjectiveC reference counting works, but a small update in code fixed the Analyze warning:

Before:

```
NSString *firstName = (__bridge NSString*) ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
```

After

```
NSString *firstName = (__bridge_transfer NSString*) ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
```